# CKFinder not working with https

Tags: jsp, http, https, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am working with Integrated weblogic server in jsp. I have successfully integrated ckeditor(v4.5.9) and ckfinder(v2.6.3) and are working fine with http.
When i try to make them work with https the images present in 'userfiles' folder can be uploaded successfully while those which are browsed and selected can not. Please help. 
Thanks In Advance!

I found following error in log file.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.clearBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:360)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.reset(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:313)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.reset(ServletResponseImpl.java:339)
    at com.ckfinder.connector.ConnectorServlet.getResponse(ConnectorServlet.java:190)
    at com.ckfinder.connector.ConnectorServlet.doGet(ConnectorServlet.java:82)

Comment: Is there some code that might have problems people here could help solve, if it is added to the question?

Comment: >while those which are browsed and selected can not.
If I understand correctly you can't upload images to server using CKEditor upload tab. Is that correct?

By default, standard configuration should work. Please check ckeditor.html in /ckfinder/samples folder. If you have any non-standard, please try using manual integration method - http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration.

Comment: Path to connector is '/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Images' and should be preceded by application context so if you have ckfinder installed in e.g. CKFinderJava folder then path will be '/CKFinderJava/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried it but still its having same problem. But I found following error in the log file(Updated in the question). Please Help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is actually thrown in few situations and from what I remember it doesn't break uploads in any way. This is not it. Could you provide more detailed explanation of what the problem is exactly (perhaps provide some screen-shot)? I have only made a guess that this is about upload tab in editor dialog, mainly because I have checked SSL on my local WLS and everything worked correctly so I started looking for a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your help! The problem was based in the config.xml file. I originally gave fully qualified path for for base dir but after keeping it simply '/' the problem was solved.